# Confirm dialog box in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

I´m trying to include a confirmation dialog in my code, but I get stucked while implementing it.
I want to add a button to my code that by clicking on it I get a confirmation dialog. Pressing the "yes-option" it should delete data in my database, while pressing the "no-option" should close the dialog box doing nothing else.
But actually, when I run my code I get my dialog box and the confirmation yes/no options, but running the "no option" the submit code in html gets trigger too, so that by choosing "yes" or "no" I get the same effect and it delete always the data from my database.

This is my html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/delete/prop" >
<p class="card-text h6"> <b>Typology: </b> <%= book.typology %> </p>
<input type="hidden" name="id5" value=<%= book.id %> />
<input type="hidden" name="prop" value= "typology" />

<input type="submit" value="Yes" class="button btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmAction()" />
</form>
```

And my javascript related to the dialog code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function confirmAction() {
    let confirmAction = confirm("Are you sure to execute this action?");
    if (confirmAction == true) {
      alert("Action successfully executed");
    } else {
      alert("Action cancelled");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't get where is the "no" option, can you post more code?

Comment: not sure, but I think you should return `false` from the `confirmAction()` function to cancel the submit.

Comment: @AndreiTornea. Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately there is no more code involved in this action. The confirm() function should generate the yes/no option by itself.

Comment: @TsahiAsher. Thank you for your suggestion. I´ve tried to return false too, but the I get the same result. The data were deleted while returning false too, instead of want I need the app to do, that is in this case to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [another website](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f13/no-funciona-confirm-javascritp-993907/) posted by @anavega.

She mentioned that I missed the `return` element in the html.

Here an example to test it :

```js
function confirmAction() {
    let confirmAction = confirm("Are you sure to execute this action?");
    if (confirmAction == true) {
      alert("Action successfully executed");
    } else {
      alert("Action cancelled");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Yes" class="button btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirmAction()" />
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: but your function doesn't return anything (or in terms of JS, returns a falsy value). does it work if the user clicks Yes?